# How do I convert a string into a property in javascript

Tags: javascript

Now I am sending length as a string as a function parameter.

```
function sample(operation){
var str="hello";
console.log(str.operation);
}

sample("length");
```

I am not allowed to change the way I am sending length(has to be a string).What can I do for this function to give me the expected output?

Comment: What is your expected output? Please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to access the property, use bracket notation for your [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```
console.log(str[operation])
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors